# Adicionar Elementos de uma classe para um arraylist noutra classe

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho uma classe `Ticket`, que cria um ticket. e tenho que fazer uma classe `CustomerService` com um `ArrayList` do tipo Ticket, a qual chamei tickets e coloca todos os tickets criados nesse ArrayList.

Constructor da classe Ticket:

```
   public Ticket(char attendanceType, int ticketNumber)
    {
     this.arriveTime = LocalDateTime.now();
     this.attendanceTime = null;
     this.attendanceType = validateAttendanceType(attendanceType);
     this.waitTime = 0;
     this.ticketNumber = validateTicketNumber(ticketNumber);
    }
```

Comment: A sua questão é de como instanciar o `ArrayList` ? Ou de como colocar os elementos lá dentro ? Tem o método `add` do `ArrayList` para adicionar elementos.

Comment: Ele quer saber como pegar o ArrayList da outra classe, até onde eu sei.

Comment: Colocar os elementos neste caso Ticket, no arraylist na classe CustomerService,

Comment: ex: pessoa cria 1,2,3,4... tickets, ticket1,ticket2..
e o programa qdo inicia a classe CustomerService, mete esses tickets todos no arrayList tickets

Comment: Acho que a minha resposta te auxiliará, @Miguel.

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisará de uma instancia de `CustomerService` durante toda a execução da sua aplicação, aconselho seguir um padrão Singleton:

```
public class CustomerService {

    private static CustomerService INSTANCIA;

    private ArraList<Ticket> tickets;

    public static CustomerService getInstancia() {
        if (INSTANCIA == null) {
            INSTANCIA = new CustomerService();
            INSTANCIA.setTickets(new ArrayList<>());
        }

        return INSTANCIA;
    }

    public ArrayList<Ticket> getTickets() {
        return tickets;
    }

    public void setTickets(ArrayList<Ticket> tickets) {
        this.tickets = tickets;        
    }
    ...
}
```

A partir dai, você precisa executar `CustomerService.getInstancia().getTickets()` para obter a lista de tickets e inserir o objeto que deseja.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo aquilo que eu percebi, a sua questão é muito simples, basta criar um método na classe ***CustomerService***:

```
public class CustomerService {

private ArrayList<Tickets> tickets;

public CustomerService(){
    this.tickets = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addTicket(Tickets t){
    tickets.add(t);
}
}
```